# Construct an extension of a number field of given degree where a given set of prime splits completely

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field, ramification

I know that discriminant tells exactly which prime ramify in an extension, and it helps to construct extensions where
a certain set of primes will ramify.

But I don't know how to construct extensions where certain set of primes splits completely, more generally I am trying to solve the following problem -:

Let $K$ be a number field and let $P_1, P_2, P_3,...,P_m$ be some set of primes in $O_K$. For any given $n$, Is it possible to construct an extension $L$ of $K$ of degree $n$ such that these primes splits completely in $O_L$?.

Comment: If $n \le N(P_j)$ then it is easy: take $f\in O_K[x]$ monic of degree $n$ such that $f\bmod P_j$ is separable and splits completely and $f\bmod Q$ is irreducible and let $L=K[x]/(f)$.

Comment: What is $Q$ here? and by $N(P_j)$, you mean norm of the ideal right?

Comment: Yes the norm and $Q$ is another prime ideal of $O_K$.

Comment: $Q$ is different from these $P_i s$, right?

Comment: Sure as $f$ splits completely (and is separable) $\bmod P_j$ whereas it is irreducible $\bmod Q$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $m$ such that $n\le \inf_j N(P_j)^m$

Using the CRT, take $f\in O_K[x]$ monic of degree $n$ such that $f\bmod Q$ is irreducible and such that $f\equiv \prod_{i=1}^n (x-a_{ij})\bmod P_j^{2 (nm)^2}$ where the $a_{ij}$ are distinct $\bmod P_j^m$.

This will ensure that $f$ is irreducible in $K[x]$ and (with the extended Hensel lemma) that it splits completely in the $p$-adic completions $K_{P_j}$.

Then let $L = K[x]/(f)$.

Comment: Nice proof! But I don’t understand why it is necessary for the congruence on $f$ to be mod $P_j^{2m^2}$?

Comment: To apply Hensel lemma and lift $a\bmod P_j^r$ to a root in $K_{P_j}$ you need $v(f'(a))$ small enough compared to $v(f(a))$ (try $x^2 -8= (x+4)(x-4)\bmod 8$ but $x^2-8$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Q}_2[x]$) @Aphelli

Comment: Good point. I didn’t understand that you used $m$ to get more residual factorizations in case the residue fields were too small. In this case, wouldn’t your condition be $n \leq \inf_j\,N(P_j)^m$? I wonder if you don’t need a stronger congruence on $f$ too (the valuation of the derivative is naively at most $n(m-1)$…)?

Comment: Me too, I'm lazy to write down the condition I only know that some function of the valuations works :-)

Comment: @Aphelli Can you elaborate bit on this $P_j^{2{(nm)}^2}$ part? Why this congruence insure that $f$ splits completely in $K_{P_j}$? I understood that it will implies that $P_j$ splits completely.

Comment: I am not able to see the polynomial satisfying the derivative condition of Hensel's lemma ( i.e. $f'(a_{ij}) \neq 0$ mod $P_j^{2(nm)^2 +1} $).

Comment: $f'(a_{ij}) = \prod_{l\ne i} (a_{ij}-a_{lj})\bmod P_j^{2(nm)^2}$ and each $a_{ij}-a_{lj}\not\equiv 0 \bmod P_j^{m+1}$ so $f'(a_{ij})\not\equiv 0\bmod P_j^{2(nm)^2}$ @Sushant

Comment: Oh thanks. So, will not any number $l > m(n-1)$ should also work instead of $2(nm)^2$?

Comment: @reuns If along with my previous requirement of $L$ if I have another prime ideal, say $Q$ and I want it to ramify totally ($P_i$s still splits completely) in $L$. What extra condition should we impose in CRT? It seems some $n$ degree Eisenstein polynomial will be helpful but not getting the condition exactly. Any hint?

Comment: @Sushant Simply take $f$ with the right reduction $\bmod Q^2$

Comment: @reuns Ya I was thinking to consider the reduction $x^n-\alpha$ mod $Q^2$, where $\alpha \in Q \backslash Q^2$. It will work right?

Comment: Sure @Sushant ${}{}{}$